# Export all product media gallery paths?

Tags: php, products, export, media

We are currently working on a Magento Migration and have so far exported all products to CSV where our client has been making amendments so that we can import the data into a new version of Magento using Magmi.

However we are struggling to figure out how we can export all the media gallery paths and position indexes for each product, when we do a standard Magento Export we can get this data but it splits each media image to a separate line however with the Magmi import ideally we would like a comma separate list of paths in the correct sort order.

Am I over complicating things? and does anyone know of any PHP Code that could perhaps iterate the products and output the list of media images to a string?

Comment: this seams like standard coding. it has nothing to do with Magento. Just parse the file generated from the export, iterate through the lines and when you find a line without sku just append the columns you need to the columns in the last line that had an SKU.

Comment: Cheers Marius, got to love the Internet and thanks for the advice :) I was so set on thinking of just Magento I totally missed the fact I could put together a quick script to parse the exported CSV to get the values I want. Thanks

Comment: I am having the same issue, i need to export the path to the media_gallery, including the labels for the images. Did you have any luck figuring it out?
Would you be able to post the code used to export it? Thanks!